# PHP Extract only a specific portion in a string between two characters

Tags: php, string, substring

How can i extract only the substring `..\/files\/listo_bfty77a3.jpg` from the main string below?

```
[
   {
      "name":"..\/files\/listo_bfty77a3.jpg",
      "usrName":"Listo.jpg",
      "size":188126,
      "type":"image\/jpeg",
      "searchStr":"Listo.jpg,!:sStrEnd"
   }
]
```

Practically i would need the content starting from the eleventh char and end at the first ".

Thanks in advance

Comment: Or, you could just decode the JSON and access the name entry.

Comment: i hav try but don't work $String = json_decode($reportdata['img']);

$repImg = $String['name'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you posted is the [`JSON`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) representation of some data structure. Decode it using the PHP function [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php); pass `TRUE` as its second argument to get arrays back:

```
$text = '[
   {
      "name":"..\/files\/listo_bfty77a3.jpg",
      "usrName":"Listo.jpg",
      "size":188126,
      "type":"image\/jpeg",
      "searchStr":"Listo.jpg,!:sStrEnd"
   }
]';
$data = json_decode($text, TRUE);
```

If you don't speak `JSON` or the data structure is thick and the `JSON` cannot be understood at the first glance, use [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to see how the data structure looks like.

```
print_r($data);
```

It displays:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => ../files/listo_bfty77a3.jpg
            [usrName] => Listo.jpg
            [size] => 188126
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [searchStr] => Listo.jpg,!:sStrEnd
        )
)
```

It's clear now that the property you need can be accessed as `$data[0]['img']`.

Comment: $String = json_decode($reportdata['img']);
//print_r($String);
$img = $String->0;

Comment: Look closer at the output of `print_r()`. If you don't pass `TRUE` as the second argument to `json_decode()` you get an array that contains an object having the properties `name`, `size` etc.